# WordPress Custom Fields issue on Post Update

Tags: php, wordpress, xml-serialization

I´m using a simple custom plugin that parses and saves external XML data as a serialized array in a custom field. This works fine, however, when I update the post, instead of the array I only see a message saying: "bool(false)".

Content of custom field I am trying to display on WordPress Post (front end) using serialization.

```
a:3:{s:8:"tb_88_40";a:20:{s:4:"guid";s:36:"26e4a3f6-afc4-457a-b34f-c09c3f4cfb1b";s:5:"title";s:11:"Casa Batllo";s:8:"language";s:1:"4";s:12:"languageCode";s:2:"en";s:8:"ticketID";s:2:"40";s:6:"ticket";s:5:"Adult";s:4:"link";s:54:"http://barcelona.ticketbar.eu/en/museums/casa-batllo-/";s:11:"description";s:3085:"
    <h3><em>Architecture of Antoni Gaudi in Barcelona</em></h3>

    <p align="justify"><span id="result_box" tc="null" a="undefined" c="4" closure_uid_3d5c4l="129" lang="en"><span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="95">The colorful</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="96">Casa</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="97">Batlló</span><span tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="98">,</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="99">a</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="100">house from the 19th</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="101">century</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="102">renovated in the well-known</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="104">modernist</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="105">style</span><span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="106">, is</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="107">one of many</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="108">masterpieces</span> <span class="hps"
    tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="109">of Gaudí</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="110">in Barcelona</span><span tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="111">.</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="112">The interior</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="113">of the house</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="117">is</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="118">just as exceptional</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="119">as the exterior</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="120">of the building.</span></span> The building has become a famous landmark in Barcelona and is open for the public. The Casa Batlló was awarded the 2004 Europa Nostra Award for&nbsp;the Conservation of Cultural Heritage and was inscribed on the UNESCO World Heritage List in 2005.&nbsp;<span class="short_text" id="result_box" tc="null" a="undefined" c="4" closure_uid_3d5c4l="129" lang="en"><span class="hps" tc="null"
    closure_uid_3d5c4l="256">Undoubtedly</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="257">worth a visit</span><span tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="258">.</span></span></p>

    <p align="justify"><span class="short_text" id="result_box" tc="null" a="undefined" c="4" closure_uid_3d5c4l="129" lang="en"><span tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="258"><em>Audioguide included available in: Spanish, English, French, Italian, German, Chinese,Japanese, Portuguese, Russian, and Catalan</em><br />
    </span></span></p>

    <p align="justify"><em><strong>Opening Hours</strong><br />
    </em> Monday - Sunday from 9 a.m to 9 p.m (Last entrance at 8 p.m.)<br />
     <em><br />
     <strong>Location</strong><br />
    </em> Passeig de Gracia 43<br />
     08007 Barcelona<br />
     Metro to Diagonal or Passeig de Gracia</p>
    <em><strong>Ticket is valid for 3 months from date of purchase! Buy your ticket online and skip the line!</strong></em><br />
     <br />
     <br />
  ";s:12:"g:image_link";s:95:"http://barcelona.ticketbar.eu/barcelona/classificaties/museums/casa-batllo/casa-batllo_grid.jpg";s:8:"oldPrice";a:0:{}s:14:"disabled_dates";s:13:"

                    ";s:9:"day_parts";s:13:"

                    ";s:18:"visit_day_required";s:32:"

                        false

                    ";s:7:"g:price";s:9:"EUR 21.50";s:11:"g:condition";s:3:"new";s:15:"g:item_group_id";s:2:"88";s:4:"g:id";s:6:"135218";s:6:"rating";a:0:{}s:16:"extraInformation";s:1:"i";s:15:"customerService";a:0:{}}s:9:"tb_88_704";a:20:{s:4:"guid";s:36:"26e4a3f6-afc4-457a-b34f-c09c3f4cfb1b";s:5:"title";s:11:"Casa Batllo";s:8:"language";s:1:"4";s:12:"languageCode";s:2:"en";s:8:"ticketID";s:3:"704";s:6:"ticket";s:11:"Child (0-6)";s:4:"link";s:54:"http://barcelona.ticketbar.eu/en/museums/casa-batllo-/";s:11:"description";s:3085:"
    <h3><em>Architecture of Antoni Gaudi in Barcelona</em></h3>

    <p align="justify"><span id="result_box" tc="null" a="undefined" c="4" closure_uid_3d5c4l="129" lang="en"><span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="95">The colorful</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="96">Casa</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="97">Batlló</span><span tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="98">,</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="99">a</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="100">house from the 19th</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="101">century</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="102">renovated in the well-known</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="104">modernist</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="105">style</span><span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="106">, is</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="107">one of many</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="108">masterpieces</span> <span class="hps"
    tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="109">of Gaudí</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="110">in Barcelona</span><span tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="111">.</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="112">The interior</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="113">of the house</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="117">is</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="118">just as exceptional</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="119">as the exterior</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="120">of the building.</span></span> The building has become a famous landmark in Barcelona and is open for the public. The Casa Batlló was awarded the 2004 Europa Nostra Award for&nbsp;the Conservation of Cultural Heritage and was inscribed on the UNESCO World Heritage List in 2005.&nbsp;<span class="short_text" id="result_box" tc="null" a="undefined" c="4" closure_uid_3d5c4l="129" lang="en"><span class="hps" tc="null"
    closure_uid_3d5c4l="256">Undoubtedly</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="257">worth a visit</span><span tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="258">.</span></span></p>

    <p align="justify"><span class="short_text" id="result_box" tc="null" a="undefined" c="4" closure_uid_3d5c4l="129" lang="en"><span tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="258"><em>Audioguide included available in: Spanish, English, French, Italian, German, Chinese,Japanese, Portuguese, Russian, and Catalan</em><br />
    </span></span></p>

    <p align="justify"><em><strong>Opening Hours</strong><br />
    </em> Monday - Sunday from 9 a.m to 9 p.m (Last entrance at 8 p.m.)<br />
     <em><br />
     <strong>Location</strong><br />
    </em> Passeig de Gracia 43<br />
     08007 Barcelona<br />
     Metro to Diagonal or Passeig de Gracia</p>
    <em><strong>Ticket is valid for 3 months from date of purchase! Buy your ticket online and skip the line!</strong></em><br />
     <br />
     <br />
  ";s:12:"g:image_link";s:95:"http://barcelona.ticketbar.eu/barcelona/classificaties/museums/casa-batllo/casa-batllo_grid.jpg";s:8:"oldPrice";a:0:{}s:14:"disabled_dates";s:13:"

                    ";s:9:"day_parts";s:13:"

                    ";s:18:"visit_day_required";s:32:"

                        false

                    ";s:7:"g:price";s:8:"EUR 0.00";s:11:"g:condition";s:3:"new";s:15:"g:item_group_id";s:2:"88";s:4:"g:id";s:6:"135219";s:6:"rating";a:0:{}s:16:"extraInformation";s:1:"i";s:15:"customerService";a:0:{}}s:10:"tb_88_1310";a:20:{s:4:"guid";s:36:"26e4a3f6-afc4-457a-b34f-c09c3f4cfb1b";s:5:"title";s:11:"Casa Batllo";s:8:"language";s:1:"4";s:12:"languageCode";s:2:"en";s:8:"ticketID";s:4:"1310";s:6:"ticket";s:12:"Child (7-17)";s:4:"link";s:54:"http://barcelona.ticketbar.eu/en/museums/casa-batllo-/";s:11:"description";s:3085:"
    <h3><em>Architecture of Antoni Gaudi in Barcelona</em></h3>

    <p align="justify"><span id="result_box" tc="null" a="undefined" c="4" closure_uid_3d5c4l="129" lang="en"><span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="95">The colorful</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="96">Casa</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="97">Batlló</span><span tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="98">,</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="99">a</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="100">house from the 19th</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="101">century</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="102">renovated in the well-known</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="104">modernist</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="105">style</span><span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="106">, is</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="107">one of many</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="108">masterpieces</span> <span class="hps"
    tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="109">of Gaudí</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="110">in Barcelona</span><span tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="111">.</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="112">The interior</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="113">of the house</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="117">is</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="118">just as exceptional</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="119">as the exterior</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="120">of the building.</span></span> The building has become a famous landmark in Barcelona and is open for the public. The Casa Batlló was awarded the 2004 Europa Nostra Award for&nbsp;the Conservation of Cultural Heritage and was inscribed on the UNESCO World Heritage List in 2005.&nbsp;<span class="short_text" id="result_box" tc="null" a="undefined" c="4" closure_uid_3d5c4l="129" lang="en"><span class="hps" tc="null"
    closure_uid_3d5c4l="256">Undoubtedly</span> <span class="hps" tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="257">worth a visit</span><span tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="258">.</span></span></p>

    <p align="justify"><span class="short_text" id="result_box" tc="null" a="undefined" c="4" closure_uid_3d5c4l="129" lang="en"><span tc="null" closure_uid_3d5c4l="258"><em>Audioguide included available in: Spanish, English, French, Italian, German, Chinese,Japanese, Portuguese, Russian, and Catalan</em><br />
    </span></span></p>

    <p align="justify"><em><strong>Opening Hours</strong><br />
    </em> Monday - Sunday from 9 a.m to 9 p.m (Last entrance at 8 p.m.)<br />
     <em><br />
     <strong>Location</strong><br />
    </em> Passeig de Gracia 43<br />
     08007 Barcelona<br />
     Metro to Diagonal or Passeig de Gracia</p>
    <em><strong>Ticket is valid for 3 months from date of purchase! Buy your ticket online and skip the line!</strong></em><br />
     <br />
     <br />
  ";s:12:"g:image_link";s:95:"http://barcelona.ticketbar.eu/barcelona/classificaties/museums/casa-batllo/casa-batllo_grid.jpg";s:8:"oldPrice";a:0:{}s:14:"disabled_dates";s:13:"

                    ";s:9:"day_parts";s:13:"

                    ";s:18:"visit_day_required";s:32:"

                        false

                    ";s:7:"g:price";s:9:"EUR 18.50";s:11:"g:condition";s:3:"new";s:15:"g:item_group_id";s:2:"88";s:4:"g:id";s:6:"135220";s:6:"rating";a:0:{}s:16:"extraInformation";s:1:"i";s:15:"customerService";a:0:{}}}
```

Here is the function I am using for `update_post_meta`.

```
function parse_file_func($title) {
    // get_tickets_array();exit;
    $language = explode('-', get_bloginfo('language'));
    $language = $language[0];
    $file = file_get_contents('http://vendor.ticketbar.eu/feed/284/');
    // $file = file_get_contents('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12344450/feed.xml');
    if (!$file) {
        exit;
    }
    $domObj = new xmlToArrayParser($file);
    $domArr = $domObj->array;
    if (($domObj->parse_error)) {
        echo $domObj->get_xml_error();
    } else {
        $first = $domArr['rss']['channel']['item'];
        foreach ($first as $item) {
            if ($item['languageCode'] == $language) {
                $args = array(
                    'meta_key' => 'tb_item_group_id',
                    'meta_value' => $item['g:item_group_id'],
                    'post_type' => 'tickets',
                );
                $post = get_posts($args);
                if (empty($post)) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    $args = array(
                        'meta_key' => 'tb_item_group_id',
                        'meta_value' => $item['g:item_group_id'],
                        'post_type' => 'tickets',
                    );
                    $post = get_posts($args);
                    $post_id = $post[0]->ID;
                    $meta_values = get_post_meta($post_id, 'tb_data');
                    if (empty($meta_values)) {
                        $new_value_array = array();
                        unset($item['cdata']);
                        $new_value_array['tb_' . $item['g:item_group_id'] . '_' . $item['ticketID']] = $item;
                    } else {
                        $meta_arrays = unserialize($meta_values[0]);
                        $new_value_array = $meta_arrays;
                        foreach ($meta_arrays as $meta_ticketbar => $tb_content) {
                            if ($meta_ticketbar == 'tb_' . $item['g:item_group_id'] . '_' . $item['ticketID']) {
                                unset($item['cdata']);
                                $new_value_array[$meta_ticketbar] = $item;
                            } else {
                                $new_value_array = $meta_arrays;
                                unset($item['cdata']);
                                $new_value_array['tb_' . $item['g:item_group_id'] . '_' . $item['ticketID']] = $item;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    update_post_meta($post_id, 'tb_data', serialize($new_value_array));
                    // update_post_meta($post_id, 'tb_data', base64_encode($new_value_array));
                }
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Can you show us *how* you're using `update_post_meta()`?

Comment: I have added that function in the question.

Answer (score 1):

When you get post meta using `get_post_meta`, the return value is unserialized automatically if the value was serialized. 
So the value will be unserialized two times and you will get false.

```
$value = get_post_meta(...);
```

In this case, the $value is already unserialized if it was the serialized data.
So when you `unserialize($value)`, you will get false.
Also you don't need to serialize the value when saving post meta because the `update_post_meta` serialize it automatically if it is array type.

Comment: I am totally agree but if I use `update_post_meta($post_id, 'tb_data', serialize($new_value_array));` without serialize like `update_post_meta($post_id, 'tb_data', $new_value_array);`. It's not saving any data (Am I doing anything wrong in the above function `parse_file_func($title)`? Second, If I use `get_post_meta` without unserialize, it's doesn't display in array format.

Comment: If I use `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tb_data', true)`, it works but doesn't display contents as we want so have to use `maybe_unserialize(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tb_data', true))` which displays in correct format but then results in `bool(false)` when update the post.

Comment: If you use get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tb_data', true), you should use $meta_values instead of $meta_values[0].

Comment: I did that but still no luck. Would you like to see full code?

Comment: @AnoopAsok, I needed to serialize when I update post meta using `update_post_meta($post_id, 'tb_data', serialize($new_value_array));` By omitting serialize like `update_post_meta($post_id, 'tb_data', $new_value_array);` doesn't store any data in custom field. Furthermore, I have to use `maybe_unserialize(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tb_data', true));` to print the results, so as far as I understand `maybe_unserialize` should be helpful to avoid double unserialize.

Comment: I have tried `maybe_unserialize($value)` but still no luck.

Comment: I have posted my answer here. However I would like to give your function a try. I will comment how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix it at my own.

I have used following code to update post meta

```
update_post_meta($post_id, 'tb_data', base64_encode(serialize($new_value_array)));
```

...and following code to get post meta

```
$tb_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tb_data', true);
$tb_meta_unserialized = unserialize(base64_decode($tb_meta));
```

I hope this will help someone.